# Spring Data Mongo doesn't persist field value as null - This doesn't works

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I already went through the link: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1107 and also I dont see option to set `spring.data.mongodb.persist-null-fields=true` in *application.properties* file.

Spring Data Mongo doesn't even persist a field having value null. How to allow to save null value if I want to do so ?

Person.java

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document
public class Person {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailId;
    @Field
    private List<Hobbies> hobbies;
}
```

Hobbies.java

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Hobbies {
    private String interest;
    private String sports;
}
```

save() - This method doesn't persist data.

```
private void savePersons() {
        Hobbies hobbies1 = Hobbies.builder().interest("Indoor").sports("Chess").build();
        Hobbies hobbies2 = Hobbies.builder().interest("Loveoor").sports("Table Tennis").build();
        Hobbies hobbies3 = Hobbies.builder().interest("Gamedoor").sports("Cricket").build();
        Hobbies hobbies4 = Hobbies.builder().interest("Happydoor").sports("Lawn Tennis").build();


        Person john = Person.builder().firstName("John")
                .emailId("john.kerr@gmail.com").hobbies(Arrays.asList(hobbies1, hobbies2)).build();

        Person neha = Person.builder().firstName("Neha").lastName("Parate")
                .emailId("john.kerr@gmail.com").hobbies(Arrays.asList(hobbies1, hobbies2, hobbies4)).build();

        repository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(john, neha));
    }
```

*I dont see lastName has been saved in the document.* Also, how to save Date as null value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data mongo to insert null values to DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112607/spring-data-mongo-to-insert-null-values-to-db)

Comment: @Triet Doan - I had checked that solution already. Is there any way if we can do it using Spring Data Mongo instead of BSONObject

Comment: I'm not sure. Can you try annotating your `Person` class with `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)`? The annotation comes from Jackson library.

Comment: @Triet Doan - Still not working. I wonder why dont see provision to save null into MongoDB ?

Comment: Could you please share the reason why you need to store `null` in your MongoDB? Normally, I think it doesn't make sense to do so. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Triet Doan - We have anlytics team which analyses data within shared and integrated syste, When they look at mongo documents or mongo reports, they dont see either those fields and its creating lot of confusions for them. Any workaround for the same ?

Comment: In your case, I think it's better to share with them the database schema. With it, they will know what to expect. If some fields are missing in the reports, clearly state that missing fields means `null`. IMHO, this problem should be solved by communication instead of re-inventing the technical wheels.

Answer (score 0):

One sollution is maybe to use [defaults](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html#declaring-defaults-in-your-schema).

> Your schemas can define default values for certain paths. If you create a new document without that path set, the default will kick in.

So if you want to "allow null", just make it the default value by adding to your schema definition `lastName: { type: String, default: null }`. When there is no `lastName` (aka null) you get the default value (null).
I would rethink allowing `null` because it would make querying complicated: Query on  key: null will retrieve you all document where key is null **or where key doesn't exist**.

Comment: Thank You ! Could you post the answer from the perspective of Spring Data Mongo ? What changes do I need to make ?

Comment: I have added an example for Spring Data Mongo. I'm not very familiar with the framework, could this `private String field =  null;` do it ?

Comment: I did like `@Field
 private String lastName = null;`, but still its not working

Comment: `@Field private String lastName = '';` what do you get with an empty string ?

Comment: Even If I set `@Field
 private String lastName = "David";` I dont get default value. In that caseI am saving document like this: `Person john = Person.builder().firstName("John")
    .emailId("john.kerr@gmail.com").hobbies(Arrays.asList(hobbies1, hobbies2)).build();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41344173/is-there-any-spring-annotation-to-set-default-value-for-a-field-mongo/41344414

Comment: I already checked that, this doesn't works. I've also mentioned the same in my comments

Comment: null is treated differently in expressions and there are performance issues for lookup-with-pipeline: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-40362

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible starting with [Spring Data MongoDB 3.3.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/3407).
For example:

```java
@Field(write = Field.Write.ALWAYS)
private String lastName;
```